# Salesforce: How to create a developer account in my company's salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have created a developer account in salesforce. But now I need to create some logic that uses some custom objects that someone create in the company's salesforce.

Should I create a developer account in the company's salesforce?

Or should I replicate everything to my developer account?

Or...?

And how do I do it or where can I learn how to do it?

### Note:

I need to use objects created in production environment .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the custom objects installed in your developer edition.This can be done in many ways like using an unmanaged package which you can create in your company's salesforce.

Your company must be having a specific edition of salesforce like Enterprise,developer etc.there is no such thing like a developer edition account in a specific edition of salesforce.means you can not create a developer edition in enterprise.

to learn about unmanaged package http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Create_and_Register_a_Package

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve your goal is using the sandbox instance instead the developer edition.
Sandbox instance allows you to switch logic and changes between production and test.

Click setup|sandbox to create and manage your test environment.

Depending on your license the sandbox instance can has different limitations in terms of space .